# How to Upload WinRAR Backup File

Tags: php, backup

I have a backup of my website in WinRAR file, I wana upload it on my new website... So I uploaded that WinRAR file on my new website panel, but it didn't worked...
Actually I'm moving my website to another hosting, so I downloaded the backup in WinRAR file and upload it on new hosting, it uploaded successfully but its not working.. it shows the default page of that hosting... check this http://kownleg.comyr.com, I dont know whats this error all about, I'm newbie... pls help
any suggestions, why this happening or how can we upload WinRAR backup file??

Comment: You might need to decompress the backup before ul to the new server

Comment: You should re-structure your question. What makes you think your site isn't working - it's best to describe the symptoms so that it can be properly addressed, else you will leave people guessing like the above comments?  Some additional guessing:  Does it return a specific error code?   Does the wrong data appear?  Is it rendering incorrectly?  Do you get a _Page Cannot Be Found_?  Remember, vague questions will get you vague replies.

Comment: it shows the default page of that hosting... check this http://kownleg.comyr.com, I dont know whats this error all about, I'm newbie... pls help

Comment: @Erik should I extract the backup file and upload all the subfiles?? cos its 100+ files, I uploaded WinRAR file directly, I mean without extracting it..

Comment: Judging by your link @RJStyle, it looks like Erik and jtheman hit the nail on the head - you should decompress your site and remove the original default.php.

Comment: @jitheman should I extract the backup file and upload all the subfiles?? cos its 100+ files, I uploaded WinRAR file directly, I mean without extracting it..

Comment: If you don't have access to the server, other than to upload files, then you will need to upload all the files individually (not compressed).

Comment: @Jeremy Its up to 100+ files, should I have to extract it and upload all files individually?? it take minimum 1hour, any short method??

Comment: It's only 3Mb uncompressed.  I doubt it would take an hour even on a dial-up.  And yes, upload them all individually using an FTP tool.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks for the help.. I meant, to upload all the files individual takes long, cos I have to select all the files individually, but FTP tool will make it easy for me, thanks for the help.

Comment: Most FTP clients allow you to drag all of your files onto it.  Try that.  Select all the files in the root eStore directory, and drag it to your FTP client.

Comment: @Jeremy yeah, FTP client tool will make it easier.. I'm going to do this.. again thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the individual files to the server using the same method you used to upload your compressed file.  The key is to NOT send the server a compressed file if you are unable to decompress it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This should be probably related to file permissions... 
Most of the hosting providers take care for security reasons.

Check you file permissions after decompressing the file. 
Should be no difference between uploading a single compressed file (and then decompress it) and upload every single file.